# How to draw a multi-bar graph based off a table made by .groupby function in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, graph

I seem to be having some issues with turning this table (which was generated from a data frame using the group by function) into the graph I need it to be. The table consists of 10 questions that users were asked to answer on a scale of 1 to 5 and the average answer for each gender.

| Gender | Q1 | Q2 ....... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0(male) | 3.7 | 1.3 |
| 1(Female) | 2.8 | 3.1 |
| 2(Other) | 4.2 | 4.7 |

It looks something like this table except it carries on for all 10 questions. Currently when I am using the .plot function with the name of this table it is plotting the incorrect graph. It is plotting this graph:

[image]

When instead of this graph I want the 3 genders to be represented by 3 different bars for each question. Then each of the 10 questions would go along the x-axis. Any help on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I updated my answer with the new guess of how the dataframe looks like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear how your data is organized, nor how you created the table.

Supposing the input data has 3 columns: 'gender', 'question', 'mark'.  Here is some data in that form, to be able to test:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'gender': np.random.choice(['male', 'female', 'other'], 1000),
                   'question': pd.Categorical.from_codes(codes=np.random.randint(0, 10, 1000),
                                                         categories=[f'Q{i}' for i in range(1, 11)]),
                   'mark': np.random.randint(1, 6, 1000)})
df['gender'] = pd.Categorical(df['gender'], categories=['male', 'female', 'other'])  # fix an order
```

You can then create a table via `df.pivot_table(index='gender', columns='question', values='mark')` and plot it as bars, resembling the image of the question:

```py
df.pivot_table(index='gender', columns='question', values='mark').plot.bar(rot=0, width=0.8)
```

[image: pandas bar plot from pivot table]

Now, creating the pivot_table the other way around would place the questions as the x-positions and the gender as coloring:

```py
df.pivot_table(index='question', columns='gender', values='mark').plot.bar(rot=0, width=0.8)
```

[image: pandas bar plot from transposed pivot table]

If your table is already created, you can transpose it before plotting, also resulting in the questions for the x-axis:

```py
df_table = df.pivot_table(index='gender', columns='question', values='mark')
df_table.T.plot.bar(rot=0, width=0.8)
```

An alternative is to use seaborn, which creates the barplot directly from the original dataframe, and (optionally) shows error bars (use `ci=None` to suppress the error bars). You just tell seaborn what you want to see on the x-axis, what on the y-axis, and what for the colored separation.

```py
import seaborn as sns

ax = sns.barplot(data=df, x='question', y='mark', hue='gender')
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=[1.01, 1.01], loc='upper left')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.barplot using hue]

Now, if your dataframe looks like:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Gender': np.arange(3),
                   **{f'Q{i}': np.random.randint(15, 46, 3) / 10 for i in range(1, 11)}})
```

For example:

```
  Gender   Q1   Q2   Q3   Q4   Q5   Q6   Q7   Q8   Q9  Q10
0      0  3.9  2.7  2.2  2.6  2.2  2.8  2.2  3.2  2.9  2.9
1      1  4.2  2.0  4.4  2.4  3.6  2.1  1.6  4.0  2.7  4.2
2      2  3.7  3.9  4.2  2.9  3.2  4.4  4.2  2.1  2.9  3.6
```

You can make the 'Gender' column categorical with proper names, use it as index, transpose the dataframe and plot:

```py
df['Gender'] = pd.Categorical.from_codes(df['Gender'], categories=['Male', 'Female', 'Other'])
df.set_index('Gender').T.plot.bar(rot=0, width=0.8)
```

Comment: Hi,I cannot use the pivot table function as I cannot access the index, columns and values in my table as they are not named the same way yours were in the initialisation of your table. As my table was extracted from a larger dataset Im not sure how to access these 3 as they were not initialised with a title like yours were

Comment: Do you have any idea how I could label all the columns and label the indexes and values so I can use your method?

Comment: Well, could you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70399385/edit) your post and add more information about your data?  If the original columns have other names, you can still rename the rows/columns of the pivot_table later.  Without more information from your data, it is hard to guess what exactly needs to happen.  Maybe you can add a simplified version of your data (but which shows the general structure)? If the table in your question is a dataframe, you could try to transpose it: `df.T.plot.bar()`

Comment: Transposing the data frame worked thank you so much

Comment: However, the bar chart is correct except it includes gender as its x-axis tick even though gender shouldn't be included in the x-axis as it is represented by the different bars for each question.

Comment: You can call `plt.xlabel('')` to remove the gender label if it is not needed. (Or `ax.set_xlabel('')` in the object-oriented interface)